# Android Studio consumerProguardFiles for the library doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-library, android-proguard

I'd like to use proguard on my library, but the file (rules) should be set inside the library. That means I don't want to set the rules w(hich belong to the library) explicitly in my app module.

I found that there is something like **consumerProguardFiles** property. My settings:

**library gradle:**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**app gradle:**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**Why does configuration above doesn't work?** I get errors that packages/symbols from the library cannot be found.

---

**Edited:**

*What is important my proguard-rules.pro for the library and proguard-rules.pro for the main app module are both empty.*

Exemplary errors:

```
Error:(3, 60) error: package (my library package here) does not exist
(...)
Error:(16, 9) error: cannot find symbol class NavigationStructureModel
(...)
```

More then one handrued errors. As I can see my all classes from the library are missing.

Comment: post the errors please...

Comment: @Shark Edited. My all classes from the library are missing.

Comment: Because both your `proguard-rules` files are empty, proguard "ate them" or excluded them out.

Answer (score 21):

You need to figure out if you want to

1. Run proguard on the library
2. Run proguard on the app (Hint: It's this one.)

#### Run proguard on the library

That's **BEFORE** it reaches the application. Your library proguard rules are responsible for making all code accessible and present but you may obfuscate internal classes.

Here's the library build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true // Yes, run proguard on the library itself.
        }
    }
}
```

If you release this library as open source you don't need this. If you don't release the library to public you don't need this.

> I get errors that packages/symbols from the library cannot be found.

Proguard builds a graph of dependencies among classes. At this point the library is a standalone unit so if you didn't supply any rules, none of the classes are ever used so proguard removes them all.

#### Run proguard on the app

Let the consumer (application) know, which classes of the library are to be kept.

Here's the library build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Here's what proguard on the app should do on the library's behalf.
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-consumer-rules.pro' 
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false // No, don't proguard the library itself.
        }
    }
}
```

#### How does proguard work

You need to tell proguard what code to keep and what names to keep. Proguard removes all unused code and scrambles names you didn't want to stick around.

You don't tell proguard what to remove, you tell proguard what to keep.

Comment: `No, don't proguard the library itself.` - what do you mean? this is used only if you separately build only the library (directly, without app module), there is nothing wrong to to set it to `true`, so please do not confuse other programmers! because you can create AAR library for example and it should be `release { minifyEnabled true }`. If you build app module with source library then this rule doesn't have any effect anyway, just leave it `true`

Comment: I mean "`minifyEnabled false` tells AGP to not minify the library". I don't address the developer, I don't suggest it's bad for you or that you should feel bad. I build some of my apps against a chain of library artifacts from a maven repo, so `minifyEnabled` does play a role as it pulls in the minified AARs. So if library B depends on A and I choose to minify A and switch Android Studio to show `release` build variant, I'd expect it to hide the stripped code from A while working on B. If it doesn't maybe we should consider it a bug and report an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since proguard might be eating up your classes, try something like this in your `app`'s proguard-rules.pro file:

```
keepclass my.library.package.name.** { *;}
```

that should tell proguard to save all classess from `my.library.package.name` so hopefully they won't be missing anymore.

Comment: If this gets it working, you'll be free to further refine your proguard ruleset and obfuscate what you need to obfuscate.