# How to use ProGuard in Library Module

Tags: android, android-proguard

I want to enable ProGuard in library module but getting compilation error that package does not exists. Why package not exists after apply ProGuard in library module?

library module build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Log Error

```
 /home/hitesh/Documents/Android Studio Project/ALPR-Sample/app/src/main/java/com/alpr/sample/GalleryActivity.java
Error:(15, 32) error: package com.alprlib.alpr.doc does not exist
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

here doc class file exist in library module

ProGuard file rules

```
-keep class com.alprlib.alpr.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class alprlib.alpr.** {*;}
```

Comment: The library knows nothing about its consumers. As far as the library is concerned nobody is using its code so everything is removed by proguard. You have to manually tell proguard not to remove any classes. Only then you can additionally tell it to obfuscate names that are not part of the library's public API. [I've been over this already here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42758629/2444099)

Comment: @EugenPechanec
ohh wow! sounds like good. can you please explain me in detail

Comment: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#library

Comment: Please see this post:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48636288/8770663)

Answer (score 11):

It makes sense to me to specify proguard settings for a library (like which library files shouldn't be obfuscated) in the library project. I've found that I also need to include proguard configurations from my library modules in my application. To do this, I added the following to the `defaultConfig` section in my library's `build.gradle`

```
consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

and then configured the proguard-rules.pro file in my library module to keep the names of important serialized classes.

See also [consumerProguardFiles](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:consumerProguardFiles)

Please see this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48636288/8770663

Comment: Here a link to the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations

Answer (score 0):

you can write on your proguard file -

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
```

Or what ever class you want to keep. 
Have a look on this - https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples

Comment: i want to compress source code but using above line class code not compressed